# How can I call a show instace to print a binary tree?

Tags: haskell, tree

I'm trying construct a function to print a binary tree, so I did this:

```
instance Show a => Show (Tree a) where
  show Null = "_"
  show (Nod x e d) = "(" ++ show x ++ " " ++ show e ++ " " ++ show d ++ ")"


left :: Tree a -> Tree a
left (Nod x e d) = show e
```

but I'm receiving this message:

> ```
> Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Tree a'
> Expected type: Tree a
>   Actual type: String
> In the return type of a call of `show'
> In the expression: show e
> In an equation for `left': left (Nod x e d) = show e Failed, modules loaded: none.
> ```

Comment: Hint: what should be the type of the result of your `left` function, and what does the type signature you wrote say about it?

Comment: I'm trying get the left side of the tree, so I receive a tree and return the left-child that is another tree

Comment: If you just want `left` to return the left subtree, you don't need to use `show` in it -- `show` produces a `String`.

Comment: I didn't understand... why not? And if I want print the tree?

Comment: Returning the tree is not the same thing as printing it. You only need `show` if you want to print the tree; in that case, the return type of `left` should be `String`, and not `Tree a` (and it also would probably be a good idea to give a more specific name to your function, such as `printLeft`).

Answer (score 0):

Your types and values are mismatched. Your function `left :: Tree a -> Tree a` says it returns a `Tree a`, but the function body `show e` returns a `String` (because `show :: Show a => Tree a -> String`).

If you want a function that prints the tree to stdout, you need to have a function that does IO, and a `Show` constraint so that the elements of the tree are known to be instances of `Show`, so its type would need to be: `left :: Show a => Tree a -> IO ()` and the body would be: `left (Nod x e d) = print e` (`print :: Show a => a -> IO ()`)

If you want a function that takes a tree and returns the left side of it as a `String`, you need to change the result type of the function to `String`, and add the aforementioned `Show` constraint: `left :: Show a => Tree a -> String`, and the body would be exactly as you have it.

If you want a function that takes a tree and returns the left side of it *as a Tree*, you should keep the type signature you have, but remove the `show` from the body (since you aren't converting to a `String`): `left (Nod x e d) = e`